# Samsung S7 (Android 8) opens keyboard unexpectedly

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

In some cases my app at start navigates to fragment with a form, but do not set focus to any field. In this case I have an issue with Samsung S7 (A8): it show digits-keyboard, that was not called to show. When I visit this page again not at start, kbd is not showed, as expected. For instance, A12 works as expected in all cases. Any suggections about the issue? Thanks

Comment: Solved the kbd issue: set to Dashboard activity in Manifest: `windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` instead of `adjustResize`, but this solution makes another issue with showing kbd in forms: fields are hidden under kbd. So I'm still keep searching for an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting up the Activity's kbd property:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```